# Sum of first n natural numbers, each multiplied by an irrational constant and floored

Tags: summation, closed-form, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How would one attack a sum like this:

$$\lfloor 1 \cdot \sqrt{2} \rfloor + \lfloor 2 \cdot \sqrt{2} \rfloor + \lfloor 3 \cdot \sqrt{2} \rfloor + ... + \lfloor n \cdot \sqrt{2} \rfloor$$

or simply:

$$\sum_{i=1}^n\lfloor i \sqrt{2} \rfloor$$

Comment: I dont know if this would be useful here $$\lfloor i\sqrt 2\rfloor=i+\lfloor i\{\sqrt 2\}\rfloor$$ because $\sqrt2\approx 1.4$. If I remember correctly this case is discussed in *Concrete math* of Graham and Knuth.

Answer (score 0):

HINT:

Since the sum $1+2+3+4 \cdots$ or $\sum_{n=0}^\infty n$ diverges according to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/1_%2B_2_%2B_3_%2B_4_%2B_%E2%8B%AF), by the convergence test this sum is larger than the sum of all natural numbers, so it also diverges.

Therefore, the series doesn't approach a general limit, so the sum has to be expressed in terms of $i$ only.